# sql query in excel

Tags: sql, excel, parameters, external

I have this query where the parameters are being fetched from 2 cells in an excell sheet, other that the one where the query is. so, the problem is i opened the data connection to change the query, since the values it's returning are wrong, and repplaced the query. now i do the following:

```
DECLARE         @year AS int 
DECLARE         @month AS int 
DECLARE         @date AS datetime 

SET             @year = ?
SET             @month = ? 

SET             @date = DATEADD( month, 1, CONVERT( datetime, CONVERT( varchar(4), ?) + '-' + RIGHT( '0' + CONVERT( varchar(2), ?), 2 ) + '-01' ) ) 
SET             @date = DATEADD( month, 1, CONVERT( datetime, CONVERT( varchar(4), ? ) + '-' + RIGHT( '0' + CONVERT( varchar(2), ? ), 2 ) + '-01' ) )
```

and then i expect fo the parameter button to be highlited for me to costumize them and nothing.
Is a problem with the declaration itself?

Later on, on the query, i do things such date >=

```
DECLARE         @year AS int 
DECLARE         @month AS int 
DECLARE         @date AS datetime 

SET             @year = ?
SET             @month = ? 

SET             @date = DATEADD( month, 1, CONVERT( datetime, CONVERT( varchar(4), ?) + '-' + RIGHT( '0' + CONVERT( varchar(2), ?), 2 ) + '-01' ) ) 
SET             @date = DATEADD( month, 1, CONVERT( datetime, CONVERT( varchar(4), ? ) + '-' + RIGHT( '0' + CONVERT( varchar(2), ? ), 2 ) + '-01' ) )
```

Those are the parameters.
Is there somthing wrong with this date declaration? Basically i have 2 dates, closure_date and begin_date and both of them accept year and month. Those are the parameters. How should i 'query' for them?

Comment: Is your query stored as a stored procedure? It should if you want to pass parameters.

Answer (score 0):

the

```
SET             @year = ?
SET             @month = ?
```

looks wrong to me - I'm not 100% sure but this might be the problem...